# How to group POIs and display labels for all members of the group?

Tags: qgis, labeling, point

My client have POI coordinates she wanted to be mapped. She define a fixed extent in wish all POI should be mapped at that extent.
I got a cluttered points at that the extent, is there a way so i can group the poi into many group, where each group are nearby poi that will be represented as one point at map and displays label for all member of the group?

I am using QGIS 2.8.3

Comment: Do you have mixed cluster groups of different poi overlapping or are they more separated?  Can you add a picture to your question showing what you have and what you want?

Comment: I have some work-around but is quite tedious and not as complete to be an answer. Anyway it might work: (a) create voronoi polygons; (b) dissolve them by your grouping attribute; (c) use multipart-to-single part in qgis **only on** those polygons that are apart from each other and share the same attributes; (d) use this layer to label your points (choose no color, no lines,...just labels). The weakest link here is stage C. For this reason I did not post it as answer, but it worth a shot.

Comment: Hi artwork21 and dof1985. Sorry for the late reply. Was working on that particular issue.

Comment: Hi artwork21 and dof1985. Sorry for the late reply. Was working on that particular issue.
artwork21 they were poi of different categories (5 categories), separated in short distance. they were all POI that was collected in detailed manner. (just like shops neighbouring each other when you walk on local road in uptown area. Didn't bring the picture with me now, though.
dof1985, thank you for the workaround. I dont think that might work. since all voronoi poly is connected, the label centroid would be pulled to entire map centroid. I have done it though, using manual check.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way so i can group the poi into many group,

There is no cluster renderer in QGIS yet, but you can support its development with this ongoing crowd funding campaign: http://north-road.com/qgis-cluster-renderer-crowdfunding/